# iOS live activities click tracking and update tracking

Tags: ios, widgetkit, activitykit, widgetliveactivity

I'm using live activities in my iOS app. All setups are done and the live activities feature is working fine. But I'm facing a problem with tracking the live activities.

1. When an update is received on the device by token-based push, How can we track it?
2. When a user tap on an activity at the lock screen it launches the App, So can we track the user's click?

I'm stuck in the middle of it. Please help me out.

Thanks.

All the properties and methods have already been tried but nothing gonna worked.